# The css from a body tag is coming along into the Iframe when becomes responsive

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a project here where I can **ONLY change the CSS** I cannot touch the html or js.
Here is my snippet :

```css
    body {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #15487F url('background2.jpg') top left repeat-x;

    }
        @media screen and (min-width: 533px) and (max-width:568px){
      body {
      background: #15487F url('background2.jpg') top left repeat-x;}
     }
```

```html
    <body onload="javascript:HMToggleExpandAll(true);">

    <iframe name="hmnavigation" id="hmnavigation" src="hb3_3_content.htm" seamless="seamless" title="Navigation Pane" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Here is the tag in the main page

```
<body onload="javascript:HMToggleExpandAll(true);">
```

And the css

```
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: #15487F url('background.jpg') top left repeat-x;
}
```

I can change the body backgroung when I change the width

```
@media screen and (min-width: 533px) and (max-width:568px){
  body {
  background: #15487F url('background2.jpg') top left repeat-x;}
 }
```

The problem happens rght there, because now, the  is getting that background.

And I don't want that

Here is the Iframe html that I cannot change

```
<iframe name="hmnavigation" id="hmnavigation" src="hb3_3_content.htm" seamless="seamless" title="Navigation Pane" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

and the body css from the iframe I'm getting now

```
body {

margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background: #15487F url('background2.jpg') top left repeat-x;

}
```

I hope I made myself understandable.

Answer (score -2):

With CSS3 you can exclude the iframe id with the syntax:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 533px) and (max-width:568px) {
 body :not(#hmnavigation) {
   background: #15487F url('background2.jpg') top left repeat-x;
 }
}
```

Otherwise you can force the iframe id on the already declared background attribute in body element:

```
#hmnavigation {
 background: url('background.jpg');
}
```

EDIT: see comments below

Comment: `body:not(#hmnavigation)` means "A body element which does not have the id hmnavigation". The id `hmnavigation` is on the `iframe`, not the `body`.

Comment: Right @Quentin, i've forgotten the space between "body" and ":not" notation.